# private key vs seed

Tags: metamask, security, accounts, private-key

I made an extra account in Metamask for my GF, I kept Account 1 for myself and I gave only the private key of Account 2 to my GF. I kept the seed words only to myself.
Since then, she has dumped me and wants my blood. Is it possible for her to access my ETH in Account 1, now that she is gone??
The funny thing is that I have access to her ETH in account 2

Answer (score 2):

No she can't access your account 1. Because account 1 and account 2 have different pk(private key), but u only gave her account 2 pk so she can't use it to access acount 1.

The reason you still have account 2, because she can't change the pk it is link to the account, but u gave her the pk so that mean u already own it in metamask. So unless you delete the metamask wallet you still have the account 2 pk and u can do anything with it like transfer all the money to account 1.